# Save data to localStorage when form is submitted

Tags: forms, submit, local-storage

Is it possible to save data from form to localStorage AND submit the form? I need to submit the form but it would be important to save the values to localStorage also. How can I do this?

Here is the code I have for the form and localStorage, but this doesn't submit the form. It just saves the values.

```
<label for="server"> Server: </label> 
<input type='text' name="server" id="saveServer"/> 
<button onclick="save_data()" type="button" value="Save" id="Save" data-theme="a">Save</button> 
<script> function save_data()
{ var input = document.getElementById("saveServer");
localStorage.setItem("server", input.value); 
var storedValue = localStorage.getItem("server"); }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, but you'll probably want to shake up your approach a bit to call `save_data` *as* the form is being submitted:

```
<form onsubmit="save_data()">
  <!-- The rest of your form goes here -->
  <button type="button" value="Save" id="Save" data-theme="a">Save</button> 
</form>

<script> 
function save_data() {
  var input = document.getElementById("saveServer");
  localStorage.setItem("server", input.value); 
  var storedValue = localStorage.getItem("server"); 
  // etc..
}
</script>
```